# Firebase query into nodes

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

A question, how I can do this queries?

Schema

```
-|conversations
-|$uid
    -|fromID
        -|message
            name: string
            date: date
            body: string
            like: boolea
```

If the user is the transmitter of the message, the followers are all collections into `conversations/$uid` and the followed users are in `conversations/ANYTHING/$uid`.

I can list the followers for this way `this.followers = this.af.database.list(conversations/${this.currentAuth.uid});`

But, and the followed users?

Add this diagram to a better explain
[image]

Comment: fromID is the ID of the followed users?

Comment: In a user from ID is a follower, but the same user insert your key into another user in fromID this user is a followed of the another user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was add two nodes. followers and followed into each profile to save all keys.

Answer (score 1):

So, with database.list, you get an array of messages.

For each message in the list, you have meta data which are added.

you can get the key of your message (so the followed user ID) with the key: `"$key"`

example:

```
const message = this.af.database.list(conversations/${this.currentAuth.uid});
```

`message[0].$key` will give you the user_id of the followed user.

**EDIT 1:**

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But what you suggest in the comment will be:

[If you use Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter):

this will give you all the conversations with this.currentAuth.uid as fromID:

```
_.filter(
    this.af.database.list(conversations),
    function (o) => { 
        return Object.keys(o).indexOf(this.currentAuth.uid) != -1 
    }
```

)

Comment: mmm I don't know if this works. In the schema If I use `const message = this.af.database.list(conversations/${this.currentAuth.uid});` I will get all conversations of the user `this.currentAuth.uid` and if you call `message[0].$key` You get the  -|fromID and that is one of your followers don't a followed. The query for a followed maybe is for this way:

I need find how many times `currentAuth.uid` exist in the node conversations as fromID param

Comment: If you ask for the conversations of the current user you get the follwers, but if you ask... How many times exist the current user in conversations as fromID? you wiil get the followed users